# How to select the element in a tree structure?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="">首页</a>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="">项目</a>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="">招贤</a>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">联系</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.item{
  background-color:skyblue;
  @for $i from 1 through 4{
    &:nth-child(#{$i}){
      margin-left:$i * 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

The nth-child(3) doesn't select that.

I try to use nth-of-type, but it's only take nth-of-type(1).

Do I need to add a class in every .item ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use the space since you are talking about children and not siblings

```
div div div {}
```

```css
div div div{
   background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <a href="">首页</a>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="">项目</a>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="">招贤</a>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="">联系</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To use nth-child you will have to change the markup structure

```css
div:nth-child(3){
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <a href="">首页</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="">项目</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a href="">招贤</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <a href="">联系</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the more correct way to select the 3rd element would be `div > div > div`, since `div div div` selects also the deeper nested levels, which might be not wanted to be selected